# jQuery & ContentEditable Attribute

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have a test case I am working on that I am trying to dynamically update a total if a contenteditable cell is changed, the total .sum cell will update the total from the row cell totals.

```
<table cellspacing="2">
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable="true">1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Below is my jQuery

```
(function() {

 $( 'tr' ).each(function() {
  var sum = 0;

   $( 'td', this ).each(function() {
    var cellNum = $(this).text();
    sum += parseInt(cellNum, 10);
   });

   var total = '<td class="sum">' + sum + '</td>';

   $( this ).append(total);

 });

})();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am playing around with contenteditable. The td class sum is added that sums the three columns. But if I change the number in the first cell, I want the var total cell to update after the change. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to `blur` or `keyup` or `input` event. If you use `append` method then you will get unexpected results, i.e the result of last calculations will be added to the current result, I have assumed that you add another `td` to each row.

```
$('table').on('blur', 'td[contenteditable]', cal);

function cal() {
    $('tr').each(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $('td:not(.total)', this).each(function () {
            var cellNum = $(this).text();
            sum += parseInt(cellNum, 10);
        });
        $('td.total', this).text(sum);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/td5Hm/

Note that if you add a non-numeric value total value will be a NaN(Not a Number) value. You can use `isNaN()` function and improve your code.

Comment: This is good thank you. One thing that I need though is for that column that adds the row columns together to be shown on page load. I will look at this code more and see what I can do so that the cells with the totals are appended to each row. Thank you again.